# Change On/Off switch for a dimmer on a daisy chain

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch

Can I change this simple on/off lightn switch for a dimmer? The dimmer has the same screws on the side. The breaker for this light switch feed multiple outlets. If I'm not mistaken, it is a daisy chain. Any possible culprit?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: As long as the switch does not control receptacles, it should be good to go.  LED lights do need to have dimmer type bulbs.  Not all LEDs can be dimmed.

Comment: Receptacles = outlet! Gotcha! I'll be using it to control the ceiling light only. My question was really in regards to the connection going around the screws and continuing afterwards to feed electricity to other outlets (instead of being a dead end). Daisy chain if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The dimmer and ceiling lights are LED compatible. One more important thing is that that same light switch controls 2x 24 inch under the cabinet non dimmable neon lights. I remove the light bulb and I won't be using them. Is this safe?

Comment: Are you in the USA?

Comment: The rule is usually one screw one wire.  This loop is to save making a pigtail connection to obey the rule.  Removing the bulbs is good for you, but not good for the next people who want them and do not know there is a dimmer.

Comment: In Canada! For the next people, I'll put back the switch. I can also look into changing the 2 neon for LED, but I'd need to change de ballast and get 24" Led tubes. Intensity will be different than ceiling LED thogh. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It worked,  thanks!